# update with combo box

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have job insert page which is working fine.
I just build an update page in admin panel.
I'm not able to show screen short :(

I need to show the category as selected which is already in the job table.

let me show you the table details.This is the job table

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobs` (
  `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `job_title` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `job_category` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `job_location` varchar(33) NOT NULL,
  `job_country` varchar(33) NOT NULL,
  `job_salary` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `job_reference` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `job_contact_name` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `job_description` text NOT NULL,
  `job_requirments` text NOT NULL,
  `job_companydetails` text NOT NULL,
  `status` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `featured` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1091 ;
```

and this is the category table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `job_category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;
```

I'm just showing data from job table for update.
but the thing is that I need to show JOB CATEGORY in the Combobox. 
I think it is easy through like this

```
<select name="job_category">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $category_tbl");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{       
echo "<option value=$row[category_id]> $row[category_name] </option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

but the thing is that I need to show selected category name which is in the job table

Comment: what?   why would you have identifying factor of a table row in another table? that makes no sense...

Comment: @Neal 
I'm just using Category table as foreign key. Because may need add delete category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the while loop you can have something like:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
      echo "<option value='$row[category_id]'";
      if($row['category_id'] === $rows['job_category']){
           echo "selected='selected'";
      }
      echo "> $row[category_name] </option>";
 }
```

`job['job_category']` would contain the category id of the job you are currently displaying.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is has some bug 
I just fixed it 
look the changes

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $category_tbl");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
  echo "<option value='$row[category_id]'";
  if($row['category_id'] === $rows['job_category'])
      {
       echo "selected='selected'";
  }
  echo "> $row[category_name] </option>";
     }
```

thanks for your clue